# How are markers added to a map (Google JS api, Leaflet, or Mapbox)?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, mapbox

I am playing around with the Google Maps JS API, Mapbox API and I was curious, how are markers actually added to a map?  Does the backend code take a set of map tiles, convert the edges to lat/long, and then simply interpolate the lat/long of the marker coordinates along the X and Y axes?

I ask because I am building an application that would need 1000-5000 simultaneous markers, and want to build my own backend system as using the Google Fusion Tables API can get expensive.

Answer (score 0):

> how are markers actually added to a map

In the simplest implementation, markers are represented as [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) or similar, and requested from the server, and then 'projected' into screen coordinates from lat/lon; see [node-sphericalmercator](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sphericalmercator) for one example of that logic.

For the 'performant' case, like [TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/) or Google's pre-rendering mode, markers are baked into raster tiles, PNG files, that show them and their locations, and you do magic like [UTFGrid](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/utfgrid/) to do interaction.

Note that both of these are compromises: you can get speed, flexibility, and simplicity, but it's very hard to get all at the same time.